# Exporting map%>% janitor::tabyl() into latex

Tags: r, latex, purrr, janitor

One of my favorite ways to get summaries is to use `janitor::tabyl()`, and using map helps me get every variable (or all non-numeric like the following example). When I do one variable at a time (e.g. `df%>% tabyl(Variable)` I can then pipe into `gt::gt %>%gtsave("name.tex")`. But when I make my tabyl through map, I can't. Any suggestions about further transformations to make it compatible with the `gt` package?

```
library(gt)
library(janitor)
library(datasets)
gss_cat%>% select(!where(is.numeric)) %>% 
  map(~(tabyl(.) %>% adorn_pct_formatting()))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After troubleshooting @akrun's answer because I was getting some errors:

```
gss_cat %>%  
   select(!where(is.numeric)) %>% 
   imap(~ {variable <- .y
      tabyl(.) %>% 
      rename_with(~ variable, 1) %>% 
      adorn_pct_formatting(.) %>%
      gt(.) %>% 
      gtsave(str_c(variable, ".tex"))
    })
```

filepath is not needed if you've `setwd()` sometime before and if you have then restating it with their suggestion creates an error.

If saving to word replace both `gt` functions for `save_as_docx(path = str_c(variable, ".docx"))`

Answer (score 1):

Consider using `imap/iwalk`, from which we can extract the column name (`.y`)

```
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
gss_cat%>% 
   # // select non-numeric columns
   select(!where(is.numeric)) %>% 
    # // loop over the columns 
    imap(~ {
        # // assign the column name to nm1
        nm1 <- .y
        # // get the tabyl
        tabyl(.) %>%
        # // rename the first column to the column name
         rename_with(~ nm1, 1) %>%
        # // get the percentage
         adorn_pct_formatting() %>% 
         # // convert to gt
         gt() %>%
         # // save by creating the .tex file name from nm1
         gtsave(str_c(nm1, ".tex")) 
   })
```

A reproducible example with

```
mtcars %>%  
   select(cyl, hp) %>% 
   imap(~ {nm1 <- .y
      tabyl(.) %>%
      rename_with(~ nm1, 1) %>% 
      adorn_pct_formatting() %>%
      gt() %>% 
      gtsave(file.path(getwd(), 'test', str_c(nm1, ".tex"))) 
    })
```

-output

[image]